# Autocomplete search from (json file) works locally not in production rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a autocomplete functionality using Tokeninput.js. The autocomplete        functionality works fine on local but fails to give updated json file in production, the json file gets updated whenever user visits the page. In local it works because i get data from updated json file but in production, the file is getting updated but autocomplete renders old data as if it is rendering from precompiled assets. Json file that is being generated is stored in assets folder. any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give permissions ie read,write,execute to json file generating...

```
chmod -R 777 yourfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing file location to public folder and in production.rb specify config.serve_static_assets = true so that application can server this file. i also gave permission to public folder as specified in comment by @chitranksamaiya